# My website works on localhost but not on my URL

Tags: url, web, localhost

I'm working for a company and I have to build an intranet (web).
Clients are forced to use Internet Explorer.

When I'm on http://localhost/ all is working (no problem).
     But when I'm on http://planning-dsr-dev.spb.eu/ it's not working very well.

For reference, here are some screenshots:
Localhost:[image]
URL: [image]
The top logo is incorrect, the placeholder doesn't exist and I can't login (can't see the error because clients' IE doesn't have Developers Tools).
I'm using the same computer and the same browser for both.  Is it a problem in my code or a network problem between my server and my client's computer?

Comment: It looks like you are viewing your website with an old version, which does not support placeholder and background-size. Press F12 and look at dev config.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me what is the dev config and how to find it plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

in the < head > balises.